# Which version of .NET is available for Xbox 360?

Tags: .net, xna, xbox360

I tried to look this up on MSDN, but couldn't get a straight answer.

It [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203912.aspx):

> The .NET Compact Framework for Xbox
>   360 implements a subset of the .NET
>   Compact Framework, and has been
>   optimized to take advantage of and
>   expose the power of the Xbox 360.

What exactly is the subset? Which version of the framework? 3.5? 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

I just spoke to an XNA buddy of mine - the XBOX360 ships with multiple versions: 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 - derived from the various versions of the .NET CF.

Answer (score 2):

The information is there, you just have to follow the articles from the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203912.aspx) you provided.

Basically, they have stripped out what you will not need to develop games for X360, that is, standardised Windows UI (System.Windows.Forms) and web-related (System.Web). In their place, it has similar functionality from the XNA graphics and network libraries.

From MSDN:

> The .NET Compact Framework for Xbox 360 does not include the System.Windows.Forms  namespace or any
>   of its classes. User interface elements in an XNA game are composed of 2D or 3D graphics (or both),
>   created using classes in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics namespace.
>
> The .NET Compact Framework for Xbox 360 does not include the System.Web namespace. It supports only a small subset of the System.Net namespace.
>
> Games developed for Xbox 360 using XNA Game Studio can use the functionality provided in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net namespace to create system link or Xbox LIVE multiplayer games.

Further information:
[Namespaces, Types, and Members in the .NET Compact Framework for Xbox 360](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203915.aspx)
[.NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx)

HTH,

Answer (score 1):

It is derived from .NET 2.0.

Resources for what is in the Framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203912.aspx